# Knime - How to use path input and output as variable

Tags: input, output, relative-path, knime

This seems a quite simple question but I could not find a straight question.

**Scenario**
I have a workflow in Knime that reads a file (excel), processes and outputs to several files. The input files and output file are in the same folder and its a different folder than the one where the knime workflow is.

I want to run this workflow in several different folders. Each folder has the same input file and the output files will always have the same name.
Now, I need to change manuallly the path to the folder in every input/output nodes, for each different folder.

**Possible solution**
A variable with the path of the folder. To run the workflow on another folder, I would change that variable only. Is that possible in knime? How?

Answer (score 1):

You can use the [`Java Edit Variable`](https://www.knime.org/files/nodedetails/_flowcontrol_variables_Java_Edit_Variable.html) node to append the same filename to the flow variable containing the path of the actual folder (both for input and output files).

Not sure how you would like to change the input folders, in case manually, you are done, you can use the [QuickForms](https://tech.knime.org/wiki/quickform-nodes) nodes for selection (from the Labs for Wrapped nodes). For multiple folders within a folder, you might use the [`List Files`](https://www.knime.org/files/nodedetails/_io_io_other_List_Files.html) node.

To set the parameters using flow variables, first you have to specify a value for them, after that you can [adjust the values](https://tech.knime.org/wiki/flow-variables) in the Flow variables tab of each node.

Comment: I've created a worfflow variable named "PATH" with the path of the folder. And tried to use it in as XLS_Locationa in Flow Variables of the XLS Reader node. But didn't work. Note: I'm a basic user of knime....

Comment: You need to use the `Java Edit Variable` node with a code similar to this:
`out_xlsPath = c_PATH + "/yourExcelFile.xls";` to create a flow variable that matches the path of your xls file, not its folder. Now you can use that flow variable in the XLS Reader node.

Answer (score 0):

**Solution**

The XLS Reader node can not use a variable as input (diferrent from csv importer, for example). 
So, i select the input file manually and pass the XLSLocation as a variable to  Java Edit Variable. Here, I substring the path of the input file and concatenate the name of the outputfiles. Those are outputed as a variable that is then used on the output nodes.

Comment: Not just the CSV Importer, but _every_ node (with modifiable settings) can be adjusted through the flow variables tab, not just those that have a special button for it on the regular settings tab.

Comment: No, nothing special. You need to create a flow variable just like you did in your solution (like with Java Edit Variable), go to the XLS Reader node's `Flow Variables` tab and select from the dropdown menu besides the `XLS_LOCATION` option the flow variable you have created. (Note that the flow variable expects a path, not a URI in case that is what CSV Importer expects.) You need to connect the flow variable to the XLS Reader node though using a red line (as you can see that in many examples).